# Pgrep conditional statement syntax

Tags: bash, grep

If doing an if-then statement in a bash script, like this, where:

```
if [ "$pgrep foo_process" ] > 0; then
other foo
fi
```

When the foo_process is running, the above if-statement should result in a true result, since the pid returned by

```
pgrep foo_process
```

will be greater than zero. But the below "do while" script, it is not detecting when the foo_process is stopped.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$pgrep foo_process" ] > 0; then
    while [ "$pgrep foo_process" ] > 0; do
        /home/scripts/arttst.sh
        sleep 2  
    done
else
fi
exit 4
```

Why?

Even when using a pgrep syntax to get a binary output (either 0 or 1), it still will not work:

```
#!/bin/bash
#pgrep foo_process
if [ "$pgrep -f foo_process  &> /dev/null ; echo $?" ] = 0; then
    while [ "$pgrep -f foo_process  &> /dev/null ; echo $?" ] = 0; do
        bash /home/script/arttst.sh
        sleep 2  
    done
else
exit 4
fi
exit 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved using pgrep with the -x switch:

```
if pgrep -x "foo_process" > /dev/null; then
    while pgrep -x "foo_process" > /dev/null; do
      bash /home/scripts/arttst.sh
      sleep 2 
      pgrep -x "foo_process" > /dev/null
    done  
else
fi
exit 4
```